# Meteor: How to add and query Dates in Mongodb with Momentjs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, momentjs

I want to show all objects which are due today. Everything works properly with my fixture data. But newly added objects won't show up.

**Fixture**

```
...
var today = moment().toDate();

    Cards.insert({
        deckName: javascriptId,
        due: today,
        front: 'blaablaa',
        back: 'blaablaablaa'
    });
...
```

**Show objects**

```
Template.showCards.helpers({
    cards: function () {
        var end = moment().toDate();

        return Cards.findOne({
            deckName: this._id,
            due: {"$lte": end}
        });
    }
```

**Add new due date to hide an object**

```
    Template.showCards.events({
    ...
        'click #difficulty button': function(event) {
        var incBy = parseInt(event.target.value);
        console.log(incBy);
        console.log(typeof incBy);
        var today = moment();
        var newDue = moment(today).add(incBy,'days').toDate();
        Cards.update(
            this._id, {
                $set: {due: newDue}
                }
            );
    }
});
```

**Add new objects**

```
Template.addCards.events({
    'submit form': function (event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var deckNameVar = event.target.deckName.value;
        var frontVar = event.target.front.value;
        var backVar = event.target.back.value;
        var today = moment().toDate();
        Cards.insert({
            deckName: deckNameVar,
            due: today,
            front: frontVar,
            back: backVar
        });
    }
});
```

New objects will be properly added to the database but for some reason they don't show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moment().toDate()` returns a `Date` object which specifies an exact moment in time (e.g. 1/4/15 at 16:32:12) and not the end or beginning of a day. Keep that in mind when storing your due dates.

Whenever your cards helper runs, it finds an exact moment in time and checks for all cards due less than that exact moment. Adding new cards will not force the helper to rerun because they do not meet the condition. In other words your `end` is not reactive and too specific.

You can fix this just by making `end` be the actual end of the day:

```js
var end = moment().endOf('day').toDate();
```

Furthermore, your helper is using `findOne` instead of `find` so you will only ever get one card instead of all cards which match the selector. If you want to see only the last updated card, modify your helper like so:

```js
return Cards.findOne({deckName: this._id, due: {$lte: end}}, {sort: {due: -1}});
```

Finally, you need to resolve how you are joining decks and cards. In your fixtures you are using an id for `deckName`, then in your submit you are using the name of the deck, finally in your `cards` helper you are searching by id. Pick one way and stick with it. I'd recommend calling the field `deckId` and only using ids (note this requires fixing your submit to find the deck by name and then use the corresponding id).

Comment: Nope. Nothing happens. I have also previously tried to refresh the page etc. When I console.log `end`,it's greater than due time in objects.

Comment: Are the new cards being published to the client? Can you query them from the web console?

Comment: Yes. I can query and I still have autopublish and insecure packages.

Comment: Oh... your `cards` helper is using `findOne` instead of `find`.

Comment: Yes, that's intentionally. I want to show only one object at time, and then set new due date for it, so it will disappear and then second object in line will show up.

Comment: I got another view where I have listed all the objects. It's working without any problems. So newly added objects appear to that page but not on my other page with due date filter. Here is the helper for the other page: `Template.browse.helpers({
    cards: function () {
        return Cards.find();
    }
});`

Comment: `findOne` just finds a single document. It doesn't find the most recent document. You'd need to add a sort specifier to do that. See my updated answer.

Comment: Still not working. I also tested find() instead of findOne() and modified template to show each object, but it still shows only the fixture data (3 objects) and no later added objects which will however be shown if there is no due date filter (due: {$lte: end}}).

Comment: What happens when you do `var end = moment().toDate();` and `Cards.findOne({deckName: whateverTheIdIs, due: {"$lte": end}}).fetch();` manually inside the web console?

Comment: I feel like the problem now is something that isn't shown like you are using the wrong helper in the html or something. Is there a repo we can look at?

Comment: @DavidWeldon I just uploaded repo to github https://github.com/mvaisanen/flashcards

Comment: You were improperly joining decks and cards in the submit handler - see my updated answer for more details. After fixing that I was able to get the desired result when running your app.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a million for resolving my problem. I choose to use only ids from now on.